# HP laptop WiFi problem

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

My HP laptop's WiFi card doesn't work.

`lspci -vnn | grep Network` showed:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

and `iwconfig` returns:

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>   eno1      no wireless extensions.

I tried [this AskUbuntu solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers), but the following command

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

solely returns

> wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Comment: What is the response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I get :  modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic

Answer (score 0):

Please try re-installing the correct driver:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If there are errors, please edit your question to report them.

Reboot.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: I tried that and the new response is:modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: I have disabled secureboot in bios, and did the sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source But I still cant connect to wifi, it just says disconnect. =(

Comment: Do you now see networks? Do you try and fail to actually connect?

Comment: Yes I can see them, but not connect "Disconnected you are now offline" it says

Comment: Tryed" iwconfig lo no wireless extensions"

Comment: Please let us see: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23734661/

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May we also see a paste of: `sudo iwlist wlo1 scan`? Thanks.

Comment: Sure.http://paste.ubuntu.com/23760145/

Comment: can it be a hardware problem? But I dont think so,its new computer=(

Comment: Frankly, I see no reason that it doesn't connect as expected. There are a few other steps you might try to see if it possibly helps. I will edit my answer in a few minutes.